# C segmentation fault Pset2 Cs50

Tags: c, error-handling, cs50

I am doing Pset2 cesear on CS50 and when i keep getting a segmentation fault when running the program. Why am i getting it and what is a segmentation fault. .................................................

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[argc-1];

    int keylen = strlen(key);

    string plaintext = get_string("Enter the plaintext: ");

    int ciphertext [strlen(plaintext)];

    int move[strlen(key)];

    int counter = 0;


    for (counter = 0; counter < 26; counter++)
    {
        if ((plaintext[counter] > 96) && (plaintext[counter] < 123))
        {
            move[counter] = (plaintext[counter]) - 97 ;
            ciphertext[counter] =key[move[counter]];
        }

        else if (plaintext[counter] > 64 && plaintext[counter] < 91)
        {
            move[counter] = plaintext[counter] - 65;
            ciphertext[counter] =key[move[counter]];
        }

        else ciphertext[counter] = plaintext[counter];
    }
 for (int loop = 0; loop < strlen(plaintext); loop++)
 {
 printf("%c\n", ciphertext[loop]);
 }
}
```

Comment: You are missing includes.

Comment: So one problem, you are apparently mandating the user enter *exactly* 26 characters for their input string? Got a lot of faith on that, do you? What if I simply enter the text "no" ? What do you thin that loop from 0..25 is going to do against `plaintext[counter]` ? Where did that hard-coded 26 even come from (and why) ?

Comment: What does `get_string()` do? Without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you aren't likely to get a useful answer

Comment: Instead of `if( plaintext[counter] > 64 )`, it is much more readable to write `if( plaintext[counter] >= 'A')`. Similarly for all the other hard coded values.  Always write `'A'` instead of `65`, `'a'` instead of `97`, etc.

Comment: Why are you iterating over `for (counter = 0; counter < 26; counter++)` instead of going from 0 to strlen(plaintext)?

Comment: You don't check if `argc` is > 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is a segmentation fault.

A segmentation fault means: you tried to access memory which is not accessible to your program.

> Why am i getting it

Because there is a bug in your program.

Without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it's hard to tell *where* the bug is. Possibly it's in `get_string()` routine.

P.S. Never *ever* hide pointers behind `typedef` (as you apparently did for `string`) -- this will only confuse you and other readers of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If `strlen(plaintext)` is less than 26, then

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 26; counter++){
        if ((plaintext[counter] ...
```

is likely to cause a segfault as soon as `counter >= strlen(plaintext)`, since you are attempting to access the `plaintext` array outside of its bounds.  You probably intended to iterate over the string rather than over the alphabet.

Comment: "is likely to cause a segfault as soon as" -- (assuming `get_string()` allocates memory from heap) not likely _at all_. Undefined behavior, yes. Segmentation fault, no.

Comment: @EmployedRussian One possible consequence of undefined behavior is a segmentation fault.  In this particular case, a segmentation fault is the likely consequence of the U.B.